# How to use signalR/Microsoft in redux toolkit and RTK Query using middleware?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, signalr, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a large scale project used by noumerous users and I want to use signalR to get stream data.
I use RTK Query for api calls and I want to update the response of api call using signalR , my question is how and where I can implement Subscribe and unSubscrib?
can I use middleware instead of onCacheEntryAdded Lifecycle proposed by RTK Query document?

my code is

```js
      async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, dispatch, getState, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
        console.log('getState()', getState());
        console.log('arg', arg);
        const currentWatchListId = getState()?.watchlist?.currentWatchlistId;
        const previousWatchlistId = getState()?.watchlist?.previousWatchlistId;
        const allWatchList = getState()?.watchlist?.allWatchList;
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded;
          cacheDataLoaded.then((value) => {
            const filteredValue = allWatchList.find((e: any) => e.Key === currentWatchListId);
            filteredValue.List.map((innerItem: any) => {
              subscribe('instrumentState', innerItem.InstrumentCode, 'instrumentState', (res: any) => {
                updateCachedData((draft) => {
                  dispatch(watchlistStateDataSuccess(res?.Result));
                  // draft.push(res?.Result);
                });
              });
              subscribe('instrumentTrade', innerItem.InstrumentCode, 'instrumentTrade', (res: any) => {
                updateCachedData((draft) => {
                  dispatch(watchlistTradeDataSuccess(res?.Result));
                  console.log('instrumentTrade', res?.Result);
                });
              });
            });
          });
        } catch {}
        
        if (currentWatchListId !== previousWatchlistId && previousWatchlistId !== 0) {
          const watchListToUnsubscribe = allWatchList.filter((e: any) => e.Key === previousWatchlistId);
          watchListToUnsubscribe.map((innerArray: any) => {
            return innerArray.List.map((innerItem: any) => {
              unSubscribe('instrumentState', innerItem.InstrumentCode, 'instrumentState');
              unSubscribe('instrumentTrade', innerItem.InstrumentCode, 'instrumentTrade');
            });
          });
        }
        await cacheEntryRemoved;
        console.log('unSubscribe done');
```

I want to use middleware instead.